# Counting words with TexCount in quote environment

Tags: word-count, texcount

How can I enter a new counter with `texcount` to count everything within the `\begin{quote} ... \end{quote}` environment?

I have tried the following, which gives me nil results.

`%TC:newcounter quote Number of quotes
%TC:newcounter quotewords Words in quotes
%TC:macro \begin{quote} [quote]
%TC:macroword \begin{quote} [quotewords]`

Any help will be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Rules for environments are specified using the `%TC:envir` command (same as `%TC:group`)

```
%TC:envir name [argument-rules] content-rule
```

and then in the command `%TC:macrocount` which counts the quote you need to use `beginquote` instead of the environment name (not sure how well this part is documented).

The code you need to insert is this:

```
%TC:newcounter quote Number of quotes
%TC:newcounter quotewords Words in quote
%TC:envir quote [] quotewords
%TC:macrocount beginquote [quote]

\begin{quote}
Text in a quote.
\end{quote}
```

This should count one quote with four words.